# What is the recommended way of ingesting large-avro-kafka messages with apache beam?

Tags: apache-kafka, streaming, apache-beam

I'm redesigning a pipeline in apache beam that will ingest messages from Kafka, the current pipeline works like this.

```
Kafka[stream1, stream2,...] -> ApacheBeam[samza]{proccess} -> Kafka[out1, out2, ...]
```

The throughput varies depending on the input stream, they go from 15k to 50k messages per second

the message structure is like this

```
{
  app_name: $name,
  metrics: [
   {
     metric_name: $name,
     value1: $value1,
     value2: $value2,
     value3: $value3
   },
   {...}
  ]
}
```

where the `metrics` array can have between `100` and `5000` metrics

most of the pipeline work is to filter the messages depending on the `app_name` and then to filter the `metrics` by `metric_name` to aggregate them.

Currently, the pipeline has 2 phases

1. Filter the messages by `app_name` and send them to an intermediate Kafka topic `topic1`
2. Read the messages from `topic1` and for every message filter by `metric_name` aggregate and push the result to `topic2`

I don't know why the pipeline was designed this way(there is no documentation about it) but for the redesign, I was thinking that I could Flatten the messages in step 1 to have them contain a single metric only.

```
{
  app_name: $name,
  metric_name: $name,
  value1: $value1,
  value2: $value2,
  value3: $value3
}
```

so that step2 does not have to filter the `metric_name` within the PTransforms, my questions are.

1. Will flattening the data be more recommendable that keeping the
   metrics nested?
2. Should I expect a performance penalty if I remove step 1 totally?

Comment: Flattening makes sense to me, but it's not really clear what consumes the metrics array, and may need data in that format. And unclear why filtering would have a "penalty"

Comment: the consumers do not consume the data in the nested format when the data is written in the output topic it is flatten and only some of the attributes are kept

Comment: Okay, well, we cant really answer what is "recommended" without knowing what is consuming those topics.